# Save Filled Area of Polygon in R

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I am plotting polygon in R and saving it.Problem, I am facing is that the whole plot is saved as png file but I want to save only the filled area in the polygon.
Is there a way for that ?

[image]

```
x<-c(0.000000000,0.010986328,0.006351471,-0.004634857)
y<-c(0.000000000,0.007232612,0.012841203,0.006199415)
file_name = paste("~/Downloads/Plot", ".png", sep="")
png(file_name,width=1280,height = 720,units="px",res=200)
plot(x,y,axes=FALSE,ylab='',xlab='')+polygon(x,y,col="#FF0000FF")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Alex I have added the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're drawing a monofigure plot (which is the default), then I believe there are three possible sources of spacing that can cause a plot element to not extend to the edges of the graphics device:

**1:** data coordinate limits that are larger than the extent of the plot element.

**2:** "internal spacing", which is best thought of as an expansion of the plot area that sits inside the margins.

**3:** margins. This is normally where axes, ticks, tick labels, axis labels, titles, and sometimes legends are drawn.

All of these sources of spacing can be eliminated with the following customizations:

**1:** set the `xlim` and `ylim` graphics parameters to perfectly fit the target plot element.

**2:** set `xaxs='i',yaxs='i'`, which can be done with either a preemptive `par()` call or on the initial `plot()` call.

**3:** zero the margins with `mar=c(0,0,0,0)`. This *must* be done with `par()` *prior* to the initial `plot()` call.

Example:

```
## generate data
pts <- data.frame(x=c(0.2,0.4,0.9,0.7),y=c(0.5,0.4,0.5,0.6));

## precompute plot parameters
xlim <- range(pts$x);
ylim <- range(pts$y);

## draw plot
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0));
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xaxs='i',yaxs='i',axes=F,ann=F);
points(pts$x,pts$y,pch=21L);
polygon(pts$x,pts$y,col='red',pch=21L);
```

[image: x]

---

Multifigure plots can incur one additional source of spacing, namely outer margins, but it looks like that doesn't concern you for this problem. In any case, I'm pretty sure outer margins always default to zero anyway.

See [`par()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) for the relevant documentation.

---

It looks like I misunderstood the question. What you want is a *transparent background*, which is different from simply fitting the image size to the plot element.

You can use the [`png()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html) function to set the background to be transparent by passing `bg='transparent'`, as explained on the documentation page.

For example, here's my fitted image saved with a transparent background:

[image: y]

Note that not all image viewers will correctly detect and/or clearly depict the transparency of the background. I would highly recommend [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), which is basically a free Photoshop knockoff, albeit markedly lighter in features. GIMP depicts transparent regions as a kind of checkerboard of grey squares, which looks like this:

[image: z]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But even with this when I save the image , the whole plot is saved but only want to slice down the image to red filled area and rest of background to be transparent